# Nginx subversion commit failure

Tags: nginx, svn

Hi I have trouble in committing php scripts to subverison. I am using Nginx web server to send request to apache server using mod_proxy setting of nginx for commiting files, svn checkout and updates works fine.

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name svn.server;
        location / {
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


       location  ~ ^/repos/.*.php$  {

                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```

Comment: Please provide more information.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that location block with the fastcgi setup for PHP.  When SVN goes to commit it does a PUT to a URI that ends in the filename for the file e.g.

`PUT /svn-test-work/repositories/authz_tests-7/!svn/txr/1-1/A/D/G/rho`

Where the path inside the repo is `/A/D/G/rho`.

The reason you're not seeing a problem with update and checkout is you're probably using a client or server that is still using bulk updates.  Bulk updates mean rather than making a HTTP GET request for the file all the contents are included in a REPORT request.  Newer clients will make a GET request and will see problems with checkout and update as well.

I'd guess the php fastcgi setup is for some sort of web based UI for your SVN server.  You need to place that on a unique URL rather than under the same URL as your repositories.